# connecting artifactory repository to nexus

Tags: maven-2, nexus, artifactory

I'm in an organization with multiple development efforts existing in parallel. My project is using Nexus to manage our Maven repository, and there's another group using Artifactory for their Maven needs. I'm trying to set up a proxy that points to their repository for snapshots, and am running into problems. When I try to configure the proxy, the status comes up as "Remote Automatically Blocked and Unavailable."

I'm not having troubles with any of the other proxies, so I think that my Nexus setup is basically okay. Does anyone know of additional Nexus configuration needed to point to an Artifactory repository? Conversely, is there some Artifactory tweaking needed to allow its use by Nexus?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got the proxy working by setting the Authentication options (username and password) to values that the Artifactory repository recognized). There were also some fussy details with the Artifactory URL that took a couple of iterations to sort out. Thanks for the responses; they sparked some ideas - particularly the likelihood of a problem with the Artifactory URL.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the Artifactory URL is incorrect. Artifactory answers a HEAD request with 200.
If you do not have a trailing slash in the repo URL Artifactory will answer with a 302 that redirects to the slash-ending URL (probably Nexus doesn't follow this). So the easiest way is to use a slash-ending URL in the proxy configuration.

BTW, having Artifactory at both ends allows you to use replication to eagerly fetch remote artifacts to your caches as they become available.

Comment: I've got a slash at the end of the URL, and I'm not aware of any other problems with it - I can browse to it and Artifactory happily shows me the repository. Time to start looking at logs, I think.

Comment: The nexus log is showing a 502 response code as a result of Nexus's attempt to communicate with the artifactory repository. And I see in the artifactory log: "User anonymous accessed unauthorized resource. Not authorized to instantiate class "

Comment: So it looks as though I need to have Nexus provide some additional bona fides to the Artifactory server, and/or tinker with the Artifactory configuration so that it recognizes Nexus.

Answer (score -1):

Nexus is checking for repo availability by doing a HEAD request against the root of the remote repository. It seems that Artifactory isn't returning a 200 to this for some reason (maybe they don't support it). You can turn off the checking in the proxy settings for this repository so this won't happen. Or you could convince them to use Nexus ;-)

Comment: Now I'm getting a status of "Attempting to Proxy and Remote Unavailable."